# For loop android widgets

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I need help as I am trying to include grid layout support for my library. This library just makes it easier to apply gui to modpe scripts. Now I am doing it so I can loop through an arrays length and add them that way so I did this:

```
var ctx = com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainActivity.currentMainActivity.get();

function newLevel() {
    ctx.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
        run: function()
        {
            try
            {
                var p = new android.widget.PopupWindow(ctx);
                var l = new android.widget.GridLayout(ctx);
                var bs = [b1, b2, b3, b4];
                for (var i = 0; i < bs.length; i++)
                {
                    l.addView(i);
                }
                p.setContentView(l);
                p.showAtLocation(ctx.getWindow().getDecorView(), android.view.Gravity.TOP | android.view.Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                clientMessage(error);
            }
        }
    });
}
var b1 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
var b2 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
var b3 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
var b4 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
```

Now the error it gave was

> InternalError: Can't find method android.view.ViewGroup.addView(number)

I never used a for loop for this and I would like a little insight if someone can provide me on how I could achieve this and what I did wrong while trying what I did.

Comment: Oh wait let me fix a few things.. forgot some properties

Comment: Answered by jonhid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to do this

```
l.addView(bs[i]);
```

Instead of

```
l.addView(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I will try it. I do not usually use for loops but when I put this into a class for the library this is the best way I can think of